# Remove duplicate values in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have google sheet that has more than 500 rows and updates frequently. What I like to do is, if there are duplicate values in a specific column (E), I want to delete the whole row (06) automatically OR extract the unique values dynamically including the other values in that row and then paste it into another place. For example, to another sheet.

Update 1

I can get the unique values from a column (E), but I'm not able to bring other values with it. I'm filtering unique values using `=unique(E:E)` function and I'm trying to bring other values using this function. `=VLOOKUP(I1,A:G,COLUMN(E:E),FALSE)` 
But it is not working.
How can I fix/do this?

Sample Sheet: [https://docs.google.com](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1loHIsauWYs7wWdqeWfDUgfJu5hKi7lQOwzW8EkjqwkU/edit#gid=0)
What I want... (Full-Size Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn2oU.png)

[image]

What I'm getting (Full-Size Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QZGU.png)

[image: What I'm getting]

-Thank you.

Comment: No code that you've already tried? Just "write this for me"?

Comment: Please don't use link shorteners as they could be used to mask links to dangerous sites.

Comment: @techowch, I didn't include any code because I have used a lot of them and none of them work or I couldn't figure out them. Anyway, I have Updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Ruben, KK. I have updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct  syntax for VLOOKUP(after finding unique values) will be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I:I,{E:E,A:G},COLUMN(A:G)+1,0)))
```

- Column I will contain UNIQUE values using UNIQUE formula
- First column in range should be  E:E. Hence New array created with {E:E,A:G}
- INDEX should also be a array. Using COLUMN to create a series of {1,2,3...}

Alternatively, You could use  FILTER:

```
=FILTER(A:G,MATCH(E:E,E:E,0)=ROW(E:E))
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation have a [Tutorial: Removing Duplicate Rows in a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates).

The goal of this tutorial is to avoid duplicates when you want to automate the process of copying data in G Suite and specifically how to remove duplicate rows in spreadsheet data.

Also, there is a working code that you can play with.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data\[i\];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row.join() == newData\[j\].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData\[0\].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

For additional real time example that was tested by other developers, you can refer to [this Stack exchange post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90688/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-based-on-one-column-retaining-the-first-row-for-ea).

Comment: Thank you for answering. :)