# Google sheet formula or app scripts inquiry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I am attempting to create a worksheet with two sheets: Sheet1, where I input values, and Sheet2, where, upon selecting a name from a dropdown menu, it should randomly choose one, without duplicates, from the values in Sheet1. Please note that I plan to add more values to Sheet1 later

"I have two Google Sheets. The first sheet, 'Refill,' contains manually added data in column A. The second sheet, 'Test,' has a dropdown in column A. When a single cell is selected, the formula ( `=IFS(A1="", "", B1="", INDEX(Refill!A1:A, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(Refill!A1:A))), TRUE, B1)` ) randomly selects a value from the 'Refill' sheet. My question is, how can I delete the selected value from the 'Refill' sheet after it has been chosen in the 'Test' sheet?"

I tried

**Issue/Question:**
I am facing a problem with my Google Apps Script in Google Sheets. I've created a custom menu with an "Delete Selected Value" option, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here is the relevant code:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Delete Selected Value', 'deleteSelectedValue')
      .addToUi();
}
function deleteSelectedValue() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var editedRange = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  // Rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tam What are you trying to accomplish by deleting the selected value?

Comment: I am attempting to create a worksheet with two sheets: Sheet1, where I input values, and Sheet2, where, upon selecting a name from a dropdown menu, it should randomly choose one, without duplicates, from the values in Sheet1. Please note that I plan to add more values to Sheet1 later on.@Tanaike, @TheMaster

Comment: Try `FILYER/MATCH` to get unique rows and then use RANDBETWEEN on  the result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077447/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/69458186/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077447/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785926/remove-duplica